# Lightning modal - Scroll to top of page when there is a validation rule error

Tags: lightning-experience, validation-rule, modal, scrolling, uiscrollerwrapper

I am making a component that has a similar functionality like the standard lightning component. I am using modal mode and normal mode based on a value provider. I want when there is a validation error, to scroll to the top of the component. I used the `ui:scrollerWrapper` component. This works perfectly when I'm not using a modal (set the isEnableModal in the init action to false). But when I use a modal (set the isEnableModal to true) it doesn't scroll to the top. Here's a minimal reproducible example.

### Component markup

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,lightning:actionOverride,force:hasRecordId,lightning:isUrlAddressable">
 <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>
 <aura:attribute name="isEnableModal" type="Boolean" access="private" default="false"/>

    <ui:scrollerWrapper aura:id="scrollerWrapper" class="scrollerWrapper">
    <div aura:id="modalContainer">
        <section role="{! v.isEnableModal ? 'dialog' : ''}" tabindex="{! v.isEnableModal ? '-1' : ''}"
                 aria-labelledby="{! v.isEnableModal ? 'modal-heading-01' : ''}"
                 aria-modal="{! v.isEnableModal ? 'true' : ''}"
                 aria-describedby="{! v.isEnableModal ? 'modal-content-id-1': ''}"
                 class="{! v.isEnableModal ? 'slds-modal slds-fade-in-open' : ''}">


            <div class="{! v.isEnableModal ? 'slds-modal__container' : ''}">
                <header class="{! v.isEnableModal ? 'slds-modal__header' : ''}">

                    <aura:renderIf isTrue="{! v.isEnableModal }">
                        <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse"
                                title="Close" onclick="{!c.handleCancel}">

                            <lightning:icon iconName="utility:close" class="closeButton"/>
                            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
                        </button>
                    </aura:renderIf>
                </header>
                <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="upsertForm"
                                          objectApiName="Account"
                                          onerror="{!c.handleError}">

                    <div class="{! v.isEnableModal ? 'slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium' : ''}"
                         id="{!v.isEnableModal ? 'modal-content-id-1' : ''}">

                        <div class="container slds-theme_default">
                            <div class="slds-clearfix slds-card groupDependentFieldEnabled  allow-horizontal-form wide-input-break full-width forceDetailPanelDesktop">

                                <div class="slds-grid">
                                    <div class="slds-col--padded">

                                        <div class="padded-row">
                                            <div class="slds-form-element slds-size--1-of-1">
                                                <div class="slds-form-element__control">

                                                    <lightning:messages/>

                                                    <div class="slds-section slds-is-open">
                                                        <h3 class="slds-section__title slds-theme_shade">
                                            <span class="slds-truncate slds-p-horizontal_small"
                                                  title="Name">Name</span>
                                                        </h3>

                                                        <div class="slds-section__content">

                                                            <div class="slds-form-element slds-form-element_compound">
                                                                <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                                                                    <div class="slds-form-element__row">

                                                                        <div class="slds-size_1-of-2">
                                                                            <div class="slds-form-element">
                                                                                <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-m-left_large">
                                                                                    <lightning:inputField
                                                                                            fieldName="Name"/>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                            <p>
                                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eget risus vitae odio ultricies pulvinar ut ac nibh. Vivamus sed est nulla. Suspendisse potenti. Donec ut suscipit ante. Cras varius eros consectetur tellus viverra, in dapibus tortor imperdiet. Praesent nisl libero, tempus nec sollicitudin vel, ultricies semper est. Duis sollicitudin orci et erat finibus, a tristique augue commodo. Nulla ante lorem, vulputate id lorem sit amet, tempus vestibulum diam. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed vel posuere metus. Vivamus fringilla semper velit, eu accumsan odio convallis eget.

                            Fusce in dolor venenatis, porta elit vel, placerat diam. Phasellus eu ligula sed risus sodales suscipit. Integer sed porttitor augue. Mauris elit sem, faucibus sed nisl eget, tincidunt aliquam ligula. Curabitur enim lectus, malesuada at est nec, semper posuere lacus. Integer eget lectus imperdiet, luctus dolor id, vulputate nulla. Sed at tellus elementum, auctor libero hendrerit, iaculis enim. Nulla faucibus purus non ligula vulputate fringilla vitae et nulla. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec tempus eros vel laoreet tincidunt.

                            Maecenas suscipit ullamcorper neque id semper. Suspendisse a tristique augue. Integer congue dolor libero, quis dictum augue bibendum quis. Nullam accumsan sed enim sed bibendum. Mauris cursus dolor nunc, non luctus mi efficitur in. Morbi sed varius mauris. Praesent sit amet volutpat nibh, in euismod nisi. Praesent id sollicitudin massa, sed facilisis velit. Vivamus gravida libero ac enim suscipit viverra vel id metus. Proin nunc augue, luctus ac dapibus at, malesuada ac elit. Pellentesque aliquet ipsum lectus, ut efficitur enim accumsan ut. Vestibulum facilisis nulla vel justo accumsan ultrices. Aliquam ullamcorper pellentesque velit nec maximus. Vivamus eget rhoncus dui.

                            Vestibulum dapibus fermentum erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Integer sagittis tortor a enim auctor ornare. Mauris rhoncus porta mauris vitae blandit. Mauris tempus interdum bibendum. Aenean porta vitae lorem ac eleifend. Sed commodo finibus pretium. Etiam vel lorem in erat faucibus vehicula vitae a ante. Suspendisse eu mauris ornare, tempus tellus in, aliquam mi. Proin dignissim convallis quam, sit amet luctus augue sodales fermentum. Quisque commodo auctor vulputate. Morbi a convallis lectus, nec hendrerit erat. Donec dapibus pulvinar lectus, vitae hendrerit nisl tincidunt iaculis. Aenean congue quam a ligula euismod tempor. Sed commodo lorem nec dolor consequat, ac scelerisque dui vulputate.

                            Cras posuere sem id libero elementum pretium. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin pulvinar lectus sed diam bibendum ornare. In dapibus, dolor vel auctor efficitur, lorem ante tincidunt velit, ac egestas lacus lacus vitae elit. Integer dignissim, eros sed viverra rhoncus, lorem lectus sagittis nisi, in bibendum odio mauris vel nisi. Vestibulum mattis pretium mauris, sit amet luctus mauris tempor quis. Nunc non mi lobortis, lobortis felis ut, efficitur ex. Ut quis nibh id turpis tristique blandit non facilisis eros. Sed ac malesuada libero, eget vehicula ligula. Vivamus eu convallis erat. Praesent eget nisl quis ante bibendum commodo. Ut mollis facilisis purus vitae ultrices. Phasellus id accumsan nibh.

                            Nulla facilisi. Praesent in hendrerit enim. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nullam mattis eget enim et blandit. Pellentesque ut nisi enim. Suspendisse ut vulputate massa, sed cursus magna. Donec velit metus, venenatis a diam at, fermentum bibendum est. Aliquam ac lectus nec dolor malesuada hendrerit in tristique sem. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus ex eros, sollicitudin dapibus bibendum a, faucibus ut nulla. Vivamus non commodo nulla. Curabitur ullamcorper pulvinar urna, non consequat tortor ornare at. In sed cursus nibh. Donec facilisis est nec erat finibus volutpat. Nunc tempor consequat massa at viverra.

                            In cursus fermentum dignissim. Nam aliquam sapien vel commodo luctus. Aenean at est at arcu pulvinar semper. Vivamus tellus urna, congue in ligula nec, hendrerit volutpat augue. Nam in velit pharetra diam euismod faucibus quis a ligula. Donec vitae leo metus. Nam dictum sit amet elit et fringilla. Aliquam hendrerit rhoncus felis, id dictum magna luctus eget. Aliquam vitae sodales nisl, ac dictum risus. Nunc lobortis ultrices eros semper fermentum. Suspendisse ac rutrum nisi, eu pulvinar dui. Duis ac ex non est mollis malesuada eget scelerisque libero. Nam ipsum lectus, cursus non quam id, tincidunt porta leo. In accumsan volutpat purus, tempus mattis diam tincidunt vitae. Nam mattis sem nisl, id sollicitudin justo elementum vel. Donec mauris ex, laoreet vitae suscipit ac, ullamcorper at turpis.

                            Cras nec sem sit amet sapien suscipit sollicitudin eu quis purus. Donec eu massa feugiat, condimentum urna sed, feugiat lectus. In pellentesque sapien ac nisi iaculis hendrerit. Aenean sit amet diam enim. Proin convallis metus sit amet magna varius interdum. In porta tincidunt nulla vel laoreet. Nullam vel mauris justo. Quisque dignissim orci eget est suscipit, sit amet maximus libero interdum. Ut molestie pharetra tempor. Cras eget eleifend lectus. Nunc posuere egestas molestie. Sed lobortis felis sed mauris finibus malesuada. Maecenas molestie fringilla nunc interdum scelerisque. Integer a rutrum sem. Suspendisse ultrices id erat quis imperdiet.

                            Aenean fermentum, est vitae viverra malesuada, lacus ipsum tempor risus, sit amet pharetra ante justo vitae purus. Suspendisse ut magna dolor. Nulla facilisi. Mauris auctor ex in ante vulputate, quis blandit lacus euismod. Donec feugiat viverra dui, porttitor viverra tellus condimentum eget. Sed sit amet lorem convallis, laoreet erat ut, congue metus. Nulla venenatis odio eget nibh iaculis, id blandit magna luctus. Quisque tempor tempus est vel ultricies.

                            Sed at auctor nibh. Donec ultricies malesuada ex eget lobortis. Fusce et aliquet nunc, vitae elementum libero. Aenean laoreet velit in risus pharetra, a rutrum arcu consequat. Mauris lacinia ipsum ex, posuere viverra turpis malesuada consequat. Sed vitae ipsum nunc. Vestibulum ut faucibus mauris. Sed elementum, erat vitae fringilla euismod, ipsum elit vehicula purus, ut facilisis nunc mi vel velit. Nullam dictum id felis eu cursus. Morbi mattis tellus non dolor lacinia, vel dapibus eros euismod.

                            </p>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <footer class="{! v.isEnableModal ? 'slds-modal__footer' : ''}">

                        <div class="{! v.isEnableModal ? '' : 'button-container slds-text-align_center forceRecordEditActions'}">
                            <div class="actionsContainer">
                                <lightning:button variant="brand" type="submit"
                                                  label="Save"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </footer>
                </lightning:recordEditForm>
            </div>
        </section>
        <div class="{! v.isEnableModal ? 'slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open' : '' }"></div>
    </div>
</ui:scrollerWrapper>

</aura:component>
```

### Component controller

```
({
    init: function (component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.isEnableModal", true);
    },

    handleError: function (component, event, helper) {
        component.find('scrollerWrapper').scrollTo('Top', 0, 0);
    }
})
```

### Component css

```
.THIS.scrollerWrapper {
    height: 300px;
}

.THIS .slds-modal__container {
    max-width: 70rem !important;
    width: 80% !important;
    overflow-y: scroll !important;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;

    /* remove scrollbar */
    scrollbar-width: none; /* Firefox */
    -ms-overflow-style: none; /* IE 10+ */
}


.THIS .slds-modal__container::-webkit-scrollbar { /* remove scrollbar -  WebKit */
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}


.THIS .slds-modal__header {
    margin-top: 30% !important;
}
```

### Dummy validation rule

Rule Name: NameShouldBeMin5Letters 
Error Condition Formula: LEN(Name) < 4 
Error Message: Account name should be at least 5 letters long 
Error Location: Top of Page

I think that it has to do something with the lightning css modal classes. PS: the  lorem ipsum is just to make some scrollable content.

Comment: r u using in lightning App or mobile APP, bases on doc `ui:scrollerWrapper` supports only for `Salesforce Mobile App`  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/ui:scrollerWrapper/documentation

Comment: @sdandamud1 hmm yea I see that it says Salesforce Mobile App but it still works in normal Experience